# Flutter Release APK does not show Web Images

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-image, flutter-apk

I just started to code with Dart and Flutter a few days back.

So far I mostly used the Android Emulator for testing my Apps. Today I created a .apk to test it but the network images dont load.

Does anyone have an idea why thats so?

[image: This is the image code]

Comment: Please share your error message for us to help you

Comment: You can run in release mode for showing error messages in release mode.

Comment: Please add internet permission in  manifest file for android  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> path android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: please your code instead of images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below line of codes hope its help to you

Add below line in `project_name/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` above `<application>` tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and **`if you display this images on web`** try to run below command for running the project

```
flutter run -d chrome --no-sound-null-safety --web-renderer=html
```

try to run below command for build the web app

```
flutter build web --no-sound-null-safety --web-renderer=html
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer it really helped